# Cannot reproduce GWT Layout examples in official guide

Tags: gwt, layout

I'm trying to reproduce some of the layout's used at the [code.google.com/webtoolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels) page, and it's partially working - I get the desired layout in a strict box form, but their examples show nice rounded corners and padding between sections. Is that something I can simply turn on, or do I have to add CSS to do all that for myself? I was hoping I could just turn it on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those rounded corners are optional - you have to create them on your own. Take a look at [GWT Showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html) to see all GWT elements and accompanying source and css.